# Is it possible to export Jenkins projects?

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to create a bunch of Jenkins projects and then export these projects to another Jenkins instance on another machine?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424228/export-import-jobs-in-jenkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Job Import plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Import+Plugin) to avoid using the REST API directly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Jenkins has a pretty nice REST/XML API, you can easily get a job configuration and inject it in another Jenkins.

Look at the 'REST API' link at the bottom of a job page (you might need to enable the plugin for that to show).