# How to export/import the Jenkins configuration?

Tags: jenkins, configuration, export, backup, settings

The [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) provides the function to export&import single jobs, e.g.:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://foo-jenkins.tld:8080 get-job myjob > myjob.xml
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://bar-jenkins.tld:8080 create-job newmyjob < myjob.xml
```

**Is it also possible / How to backup&restore the configs?**

---

I mean the whole settings:

- the system configuration,
- the global security configuration,
- the credentials,
- the global tool configuration,
- the plugins configuration (the "HTTP Proxy Configuration" and the list of the installed plugins)
- the nodes
- the users
- <sub>is anything missing?</sub>

The whole settings at once or maybe even as single backup/restore processes like e.g. MozBackup with its "Components selection"

[image: MozBackup - Components selection]

or eclipse with its "Export Preferences" dialog

[image: eclipse - Export Preferences]

Comment: maybe use Configuration as Code + Jenkins Job DSL? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/casc/ (not sure if these are stable enough)

Answer (score 39):

There is no simple way to backup/export selected parts of the configuration, since **Jenkins configuration data is scattered** among

- several files (global `config.xml`, lots of plugin-specific files)
- several sub-directories (credentials, nodes) and
- some of the files are encrypted (credentials), so you must also backup the encryption keys

The cleanest solution will be to **back-up the *entire* `$JENKINS_HOME`**, and to **exclude those parts that you do *not* want to be part of the backup** (e.g., exclude `jobs/*/builds`). With that you'll end up with a resonable backup size also.

Such a backup must be done on filesystem level, as there's no API to access all those files/data.

**Do not rely on `thinBackup`**, as you depend on the plugin maintainers to not  miss anything important. E.g., as of version 1.7.4, `thinBackup` does not backup Jenkins' secret keys, so it's impossible to restore credentials from scratch.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe [thinBackup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup) will help you.

Answer (score -12):

The mentioned requirement can be easily achieved using the below plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin

Below issues will be solved while using this plugin

- Config changes are versioned
- Config changes can be compared
- Config changes can be reverted back