# Migrating settings between two instances of jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

How can I migrate settings  between two instances of jenkins. 
I would like to configure an instance of Jenkins version 1.642.1 using a script.

I have an existing jenkins with  the setting I want.  It runs at

http://oldjenkins:8080

I have used ansible, vagrant to provision a new instance of jenkins with  plugins on a new server. I have used JJB to copy the job configs I need.

The old jenkins has some more setting I want to  migrate

- http://oldjenkins:8080/credential-store/domain/_/
- http://oldjenkins:8080/configure
- http://oldjenkins:8080/configfiles

How can I do this using a script or provisioning tool? Is there some export: import process which I need to learn about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Migrating settings** between two different masters is **very similar to backup/restoring Jenkins settings** in one and the same master.

See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585734/how-to-export-import-the-jenkins-configuration/38606016) for more information on that.

There's one additional caveat, though: **host-specific settings** (like Jenkins URL in the global configuration) must be adapted **manually**.

Comment: So  the  procedure is to copy the $JENKINS_HOME dir and exclude the parts which are not needed.  Their is a plugin to do this  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup and its not maintained.

Comment: I'm not a friend of `thinBackup`. You must rely on the maintainers of that plugin that they won't miss anything important. As of now, e.g. secret keys will not be backuped, so you won't be able to restore credentials from a thinBackup. I'd rather copy on filesystem level, or go with a real backup package.