# Jenkins service won't start after backup

Tags: jenkins, backup

My organization needs to make backups of our heavily customized Jenkins instance. After doing some research on different methods for backing up Jenkins, we decided to go the route of copying the whole Jenkins directory using `xcopy` and then moving the backup to a new instance on a different machine. (The reason for using `xcopy` is that its the only way to preserve they symbolic link files within each job.)

Here's the steps I have taken:

1. A batch file uses `xcopy` to copy the entire `D:\Jenkins` directory on a nightly basis from the old machine
2. I install a fresh instance of Jenkins on a new server
3. I stop the Jenkins service from running
4. I delete the current Jenkins directory in the new machine and then `xcopy` the backup in its place
5. I attempt to start the Jenkins service and I am met with the following error:

> The Jenkins service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some
>   services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services
>   or programs.

I have tried running `jenkins.war` from the command line and that just causes a Jenkins instance to start up that doesn't register as a windows service, and I cannot login to (even after disabling `useSecurity`), and looks like it doesn't have our modifications present.

I have also tried clearing the application log and that did not help.

I am not sure how to get the Jenkins service up and running.

Answer (score 1):

The one folder you need to backup is the one referenced by [the environment variable `JENKINS_HOME`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins)

It is best to keep that folder separate from the installation folder like `C:\Program Files (x86)\jenkins`.

Then I prefer using a [tomcat instance, and copy the jenkins.war in it](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tomcat): it is easier to upgrade:

> Simply overwrite your jenkins.war with the new version. Tomcat should automatically redeploy the application.

Comment: @TaylorLiss directly as `java -jar jenkins.war`, I suppose?

Comment: I checked in our configuration page for Jenkins and `Home Directory` is set to `D:/Jenkins`. So wouldn't that mean I would need to copy the whole folder (as I've been trying to do?)

Comment: @TaylorLiss yes, except for the files needed to run jenkins itself (like jenkins.war). That is why I recommend setting the Home Directory for Jenkins not where jenkins.war is. Otherwise, you would get https://stackoverflow.com/a/38606016/6309