# How do I bootstrap Jenkins Jobs

Tags: jenkins

I need to bootstrap Jenkins Server along with it's plugins and jobs.

I know that for plugin installation you can just place the hpi file into the ./plugins folder.

But what about jobs?
How do I set up the jobs? , I have the xml job definition extracted from the one that I created manually.

But how can I automatically install the jobs during server build?
I know about jenkins-cli, but for some reason it keeps giving me an IO error.

Does anyone know any other way to pre-set up the jobs?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export/import jobs in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424228/export-import-jobs-in-jenkins)

Comment: Put them in $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<job name>/config.xml and restart Jenkins