# Is there a way how to convert Jenkins project into Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I do have existing project which has a few steps and I would like to have exactly same thing with multibranch support. Multi branch project is looking good but I need to use Pipeline and create Jenkinsfile, but when it comes to Pipelines I do struggle to find good documentation and examples.

So an idea is that it would be really handy, if I can convert existing project into Pipeline because that would really help.

Is there a way how this can be done or do I have to write Jenkinsfile from scratch?

Comment: Not used it but you could try https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Convert+To+Pipeline+Plugin

Comment: Can someone explain why this question was closed?

Comment: agree, seems like a reasonable question to me. i wonder what guildine was violated.

Comment: Not my close vote, but questions asking for software recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. This could perhaps be refactored into a "how can I" question but then the OP should contain at least a modicum of research effort.

Comment: I disagree, pipeline is something what you need to program also question popularity clearly shows people are interested so "purity of questions" vs reality of real world problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know a tool that converts existing project to pipeline project, so I guess you'd have to start from scratch.

The documentation is not great but there are plenty of resource to follow:

- [Jenkins.io book pipeline section](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/)
- [Pipeline steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/) and [workflow-basic-steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/)
- [fabric8](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library) - great examples on how to use the [Shared Groovy Library Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Shared+Groovy+Libraries+Plugin)
- http://your-jenkins/pipeline-syntax/ - Pipeline Snippet Generator and /pipeline-syntax/globals for global variable reference

Comment: your-jenkins link is out of date

Comment: @RMorrisey your-jenkins is meant as *your* jenkins host url address. The pipeline-syntax page is part of jenkins installation.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tried it, but I've seen that [others have](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16360?focusedCommentId=281696&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-281696). Use this to translate your current project's config.xml: 
https://github.com/visualphoenix/jenkins-xml-to-jobdsl

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424228/export-import-jobs-in-jenkins for how to obtain the XML.

Answer (score 0):

This may help. it says auto convert from free style to pipeline - https://jenkinsworld20162017.sched.com/event/Bk3r/auto-convert-your-freestyle-jenkins-jobs-to-coded-pipeline?iframe=no&w=100%&sidebar=yes&bg=no