# Suggest a jenkins plugin to import jobs from remote machine ? (not from two servers in same machine)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have some jobs in a jenkins hosted in a mac machine. Is there a way to import all these jobs to a jenkins server in a different machine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424228/export-import-jobs-in-jenkins or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424228/export-import-jobs-in-jenkins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export/import jobs in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424228/export-import-jobs-in-jenkins)